# Extracting type or interface name from Generic Type as a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am fairly new to TypeScript so bear with me.

Basically, I am trying to extract the name of the type/interface from my generic type. 
Here is some code to explain:

```
interface Account {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
}

// I know this is completely wrong but just wanted to show what my idea is.
// I just want a function to be able to return the name of my interface as a string.
const returnNameOfInterface = <T>() => {
  return nameOf T;
}

const name = returnNameOfInterface<Account>(); // This would return 'Account'
```

Obviously, the code above isn't correct but I just want to give an example of what my end goal is.

**Edit**

Here is an example to that I hope better explains what I am trying to accomplish:

```
interface Account {
  id: string;
  accountName: string;
}

interface AccountInput {
  id: string | null | undefined;
  accountName: string | null | undefined;
}

interface Contact {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
}

interface ContactInput {
  id: string | null | undefined;
  firstName: string | null | undefined;
}


const returnFieldsFromEntity = (entity: string) => {
  if (entity === 'Account') {
    return { id: undefined, accountName: undefined, accountField1: undefined, accountField2: undefined }
  }

  if (entity === 'Contact') {
    return { id: undefined, firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined }
  }
}

const accountInput = {
  id: '1',
  accountName: 'Amazon',
}

const contactInput = {
  id: '1',
  firstName: 'Sam',
}

const allDataUsingNameOfType = <T, P = any>(data: P): T => {
  const fields = returnFieldsFromEntity(nameOf T); // nameOf T would return 'Account' or 'Contact'

  const mergeData = { ...fields, ...data };

  return mergeData;
}

const allDataUsingEntityParam = <T, P = any>(data: P, entity: string): T => {
  const fields = returnFieldsFromEntity(entity); // nameOf T would return 'Account' or 'Contact'

  const mergeData = { ...fields, ...data };

  return mergeData;
}



const getAllAccountData = allDataUsingNameOfType<Account, AccountInput> (accountInput); // This would return { id: '1', accountName: 'Amazon, accountField1: undefined, accountField2: undefined } which would be a typeof Account
const getAllContactData = allDataUsingNameOfType<Contact, ContactInput> (contactInput); // This would return { id: '1', firstName: 'Sam', lastName: undefined } which would be a typeof Contact

// This would use a separate parameter in my function to know what my entity is. This seems redundant when the interface name is the same as the entity name.
const getAllAccountData1 = allDataUsingEntityParam<Account, AccountInput>(accountInput, 'Account'); // This would return { id: '1', accountName: 'Amazon, accountField1: undefined, accountField2: undefined } which would be a typeof Account
const getAllContactData1 = allDataUsingEntityParam<Contact, ContactInput>(contactInput, 'Contact'); // This would return { id: '1', firstName: 'Sam', lastName: undefined } which would be a typeof Contact
```

Comment: You cannot get compile time thing like interface in runtime. Interface name you want doenst exists in the moment when the function is called. What you can do is have a value representing the interface and get some property of the value.

Comment: Basically what you're trying to do is not possible without repetition. If I were you I wouldn't worry about explicitly setting fields to an 'undefined' value, but instead just leave those properties completely unset. Also look into Partial as it makes a few things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons you can't do this.

1. Interfaces do not exist at runtime. After compilation your code is just `returnNameOfInterface()` so any identifier of the interface is just completely gone. This means the compiled javascript could not possibly get any information from the type being passed in.
2. Typescript uses value based typing, not identity based typing. Meaning that if the shape of two interfaces are the same, then the interfaces *are the same*. Therefore, what would you expect the following to return?

```
interface Account {
  id: string;
  firstName: string;
}

returnNameOfInterface<{
  id: string
  firstName: string
}>();
```

The point being that getting the name of an interface is not as simple of an operation as you might think.

---

Whatever you are trying to do, I guarantee there is a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Alex. That does make sense. Basically, I am trying to get the name of the interface because I want to pass the name down to a function as a parameter.

Comment: @ATBTechnologies way easier to just add a property to the interface with the name you want.

Comment: @Evert How would that help me? Do you have an example?